# Java method not found running on oracle database

Tags: java, oracle, plsql

I have can not deal with execute my java method on oracle server. I load my java class on database using loadjava and create function using this query:

```
create or replace function getPeriodIdDay (multiplicity number, stardDate date, endDate date) return number
as language java
name 'Period.getPeriodIdDay(int, oracle.sql.Date, oracle.sql.Date) return int';
```

My method in class is:

```
  public static int getPeriodIdDay(int multiplicity, DATE startDate, DATE date){
       // day period calculation
       int dayPeriodId =  (date.dateValue().getTime() - startDate.dateValue().getTime()) / MILLIS_IN_DAY;
       return dayPeriodId / multiplicity;
   }
```

Each time when try to execute this function I have get this error:

```
29531. 00000 -  "no method %s in class %s"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to execute a non-existent method in a
           Java class.
*Action:   Adjust the call or create the specified method.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The signature of the java method in your function declaration is:

```
Period.getPeriodIdDay(int, oracle.sql.Date, oracle.sql.Date) return int
```

but the signatur of the metho in the java class itself is:

```
int getPeriodIdDay(int multiplicity, DATE startDate, DATE date)
```

If the capitalisation of `DATE` is no mistake when copying it here then this is a different type.

And even if it is a copy mistake: check with the imports of the java class that the same `Date` class is used.

Comment: Yep, u have right i should use `DATE` insted of `Date`.

Answer (score 1):

the problem seems to be the **DATE** class, I suggest you to use **String** instead

You better change your method class like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE AND RESOLVE JAVA SOURCE NAMED JTESTDATE AS 
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class TestDate {
    public static int getDate(int multiplicity, String startDate,
            String endDate) {
        SimpleDateFormat sf = new SimpleDateFormat();
        sf.applyPattern("yyyymmdd");//You Have to specify format here
        Date sd;
        try {
            sd = sf.parse(startDate);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return -1;
        }
        Date ed;
        try {
            ed = sf.parse(endDate);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return -2;
        }
        long dayPeriodId = (ed.getTime() - sd.getTime()) / 24 * 60 * 60;//this is replaced with your code
        return (int) (dayPeriodId / multiplicity);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, that was mistake, function name in oracle and java are the same.